# Achemso: optional note in first citation reference creates extra bibliography entry and odd numbering

Tags: bibliographies, citing, achemso

Using `achemso` class, is there a way to avoid the superfluous bibliography entry when the first citation contains an optional note? In such cases, the demonstration example warns us than `achemso` "assumes that the whole work has already been cited: odd numbering will result if this is not the case."

Why, and is there an alternative or workaround? MWE illustrates undesired default behavior when using `\cite` with optional note to give a specific page number:

```
\documentclass{achemso}% 

\begin{filecontents}{example.bib}
@Article{ref1,
  author   = {Author},
  title    = {Title of work},
  date    = {2014}
} \end{filecontents} 

\title{Test of citations with optional note in achemso}

\begin{document}

Here is the first and so far only reference \cite[p.~x]{ref1}, %
but two bibliography entries are made~\ldots

\bibliography{example}
\end{document}
```

Instead of the following (with note 1 never appearing in the text):

> (1) Author,
>   (2) Ref. 1, p. x.

I want:

> (1) Author, p. x.

Later in my document I may refer to other parts of the same work (so cannot specify pages in the `.bib` file). Also, the citation style uses superscripts; thus there is no parenthetical text (as per `natbib`'s `\citep`) in which to put the optional note.

Comment: Notes never get moved from the 'citation' to 'bibliography' part, I'm afraid: the two are essentially independent. Indeed, the editorial office will probably ask you to have one reference, for the boo (?) itself, and to use 'ref. X, p. Y' in the running text.

Comment: Thank you for the speedy reply clarifying editorial expectations. I suppose if I have enough of these instances, I could try redefining \citep to shift optional notes into the running text for publications that use achemso style, while allowing me to keep the notes with the command for convenience of use elsewhere (e.g. a dissertation).

Answer (score 3):

The approach taken by the `achemso` class follows the approach taken by the ACS in publications. Page numbers are given in ACS publications as part of references section, as in all chemistry journals I know of. As such details are not moved from a `\cite` command to the references section, it's therefore expected that the information is given as part of the reference, if appropriate. For a journal article this would never be the case anyway: it's only for books that such information is given.